# Docusign Connect can not deserialize response

Tags: docusignapi, xml-deserialization

I used Visual Studio's wsdl.exe to create a class file based upon https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl.

The code is straightforward:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BusinessObjects.Docusign.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream());

BusinessObjects.Docusign.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation envelopeStatus = (BusinessObjects.Docusign.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)serializer.Deserialize(reader)
```

;

The deserializer is compaining that this now was unexpected:

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by declaring the default namespace when instantiating the XmlSerializer

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocuSignEnvelopeInformation), "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0");
```

And by adding this decorator to the generated DocuSignEnvelopeInformation class

```
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot (ElementName = "DocuSignEnvelopeInformation")]
```